# VBA loop with InStr for a .txt file

Tags: excel, import, vba

I have problems trying to import info from a `.txt file`. I have this data inside the file:

```
EMPRESA : TRANSENER S.A.                
---- NODO --------------------         INYECCION
Descripción                     VNom       (MW)
ALICURA     500        2         500      251.8
---- LINEAS ------------------         PARTIC  CHPOTik  REMUNERACION
Descripción                     VNom      (%)    ($/H)  MENSUAL  ($)
ACABRAL-R.OESTE 500.0            500     0.15     5.24       3775.62
ALMAFUE.-ACABRAL 500.0           500     0.15     1.85       1335.12
------------------------------
---- NODO --------------------         INYECCION
Descripción                     VNom       (MW)
SANTO TOME  500  2               500      101.2
---- LINEAS ------------------         PARTIC  CHPOTik  REMUNERACION
Descripción                     VNom      (%)    ($/H)  MENSUAL  ($)
ALMAFUE.-EMBALSE-500-1           500     0.15     0.25        179.54
CHACO500-RESISTEN 500.0          500     0.10     0.17        124.02
------------------------------
---- NODO --------------------         INYECCION
Descripción                     VNom       (MW)
ALMAFUERTE    1.0     3            1       -9.5
---- LINEAS ------------------         PARTIC  CHPOTik  REMUNERACION
Descripción                     VNom      (%)    ($/H)  MENSUAL  ($)
ALMAFUE.-EMBALSE-500-1           500     0.15     0.25        179.54
CHACO500-RESISTEN 500.0          500     0.10     0.17        124.02
```

I want to extract for any BUS (NODO) the information:

```
Name                             Vnom    ( MW ) 
ALICURA     500        2         500      251.8 
SANTO TOME  500  2               500      101.2
ALMAFUERTE    1.0     3            1       -9.5
```

I make this code, but only works with the first one:

```
Private Sub BarrasIny_Click()
    Dim myFile As String
    Dim text As String
    Dim quote As String
    Dim textline As String

    myFile = "C:\Users\tvelis\Desktop\CFCT_por_barra2.txt"

    Open myFile For Input As #1
        Do Until EOF(1)
            Line Input #1, textline
            text = text & textline
        Loop
    Close #1

    quote = InStr(text, "---- NODO")
    Range("A1").Value = "Barra"
    Range("B1").Value = "Tension"
    Range("c1").Value = "MW"

    Range("A2").Value = Mid(text, quote + 103, 30)
    Range("B2").Value = Mid(text, quote + 136, 3)
    Range("C2").Value = Mid(text, quote + 145, 5)
End Sub
```

How can I do to make a Loop and extract the information from any bus(NODO)?

Answer (score 0):

I've tried the following and I believe it is very close to what you are trying to achieve, used a counter to check for the NODO and get the values two lines below, then get the values of the textline and split them into an array, then looped through the array to place the values into the Sheet:

```
Private Sub BarrasIny_Click()
    Dim myFile As String
    Dim text As String
    Dim quote As String
    Dim textline As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
    'declare and set your worksheet, amend as required
    Dim arr(0) As Variant
    myFile = "C:\Users\tvelis\Desktop\CFCT_por_barra2.txt"
    counter = 0

    Open myFile For Input As #1
        Do Until EOF(1)
            Line Input #1, textline
            counter = counter + 1
            If InStr(textline, "--- NODO") > 0 Then counter = 0

            If counter = 2 Then
                LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
                b = 2
                arr(0) = Split(textline, " ")
                For c = LBound(arr(0)) To UBound(arr(0))
                    If arr(0)(c) <> "" Then
                        If Not IsNumeric(arr(0)(c)) Then
                            ws.Cells(LastRow, 1).Value = Trim(ws.Cells(LastRow, 1).Value & " " & arr(0)(c))
                            y = LastRow
                        Else
                            ws.Cells(y, b).Value = arr(0)(c)
                            b = b + 1
                        End If
                        x = x + 1
                    End If
                Next c
            End If
        Loop
    Close #1

    ws.Range("A1").Value = "Barra"
    ws.Range("B1").Value = "Tension"
    ws.Range("C1").Value = "MW"
End Sub
```